# Comparing Nullable Bits

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In Transact-SQL, what's the best way to compare two bit values that can be 0, 1, or NULL?

For example, in stored procedure that UPDATEs a bit column with a parameter value, I'd like to only perform the update if the parameter value is different from the value in the table (the values in the table and the parameter can be 0, 1 or NULL).

I'm considering:

```
WHERE …
AND (CASE WHEN b=@b OR COALESCE(b,@b) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 1
```

vs.

```
WHERE …
AND EXISTS (SELECT b EXCEPT SELECT @b)
```

Is there a good reason to prefer one over the other?  Is there a better way to do this?

In this case, only one row will be updated, so I don't think performance is a big issue, unless there's a large difference.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid `... and not ( b = @b or ( b is null and @b is null ) )`? Or `... and Coalesce( b, -1 ) != Coalesce( @b , -1 )`? If the remainder of the `where` clause has already narrowed the query down to a single row it is unlikely that the overhead of this logic will have a significant impact on performance. Of course, it's possible that only one row has a bit to flip out of several rows identified by the remainder of the `where` ... .

Comment: Basically, what you want is something like this: `WHERE ...(@b = b or (@b is null and b is null)`. This is a [sargable.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean) predicate, unlike `coalesce(@b, b) is null`

Comment: @HABO, I can't use -1 with a bit.  The remainder of the WHERE specifies the primary key, so it's always 1 row.  No real reason to prefer COALESCE over the (@b is null and @b is null) other than it seems more elegant to me.  Maybe it isn't.

Comment: @ZoharPeled are you also suggesting using the first method but replacing the COALESCE with the (@b is null and b is null)?  I don't think sargability comes into play in this case, since the rest of the WHERE specifies a PK, so that will be used to get to the row.

Comment: @HABO your suggestion doesn't work with NULLs, in the case where one of the values is NULL and the other isn't.

Comment: Maybe I should have added to the question that I'm taking advantage of the ELSE in the CASE expression, and the EXCEPT functionality to handle the troublesome cases with a single NULL value.  Avoids elaborate expression.

Comment: @GilM `Coalesce` follows the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so `Coalesce( b, -1 )` will return an `int`. Zohar Peled's suggestion of `(@b = b or (@b is null and b is null)` is the opposite of what you want and ought to be prefixed with `not` (as my first expression was), Could you show where my examples fail with one null and one non-null value?

Comment: @habo correct, I've missed that...

Comment: I'm suggesting the first method, yes.

Comment: @HABO   (assume at-signs before b1 and b2)  

DECLARE b1 bit = 1, b2 bit = NULL;  
IF NOT (b1=b2 OR (b1 IS NULL AND b2 IS NULL)) PRINT 'IT     WORKS'   
ELSE PRINT 'IT FAILS';

Comment: Right you are! I take (little) solace in not being the only one to muck up three-valued logic.

Comment: I think the COALESCE(,-1) pattern is what I should do, though.  I should have tried it.  I just assumed it had to match the type of the first parameter.  So, you did help!

Comment: Another option is `IIF(ISNULL(NULLIF(@b, b), NULLIF(b, @b)) IS NULL, 'equal', 'different')`, but the first option I've suggested is more readable (even if you need to reverse it)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with ...AND COALESCE(@b,-1) != COALESCE(b,-1)  
I think it's the most readable and clear.  I didn't know that COALESCE would allow the second parameter to be an int if the first was a bit.  If @HABO wants to submit it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data being compared are nullable `bit` values you can use `Coalesce( B, -1 ) = Coalesce( @B, -1 )` to perform matching of all three values (`0`, `1` and `NULL`) by mapping them to `0`, `1` and `-1`.

[`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) follows the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Given a `bit` (`B`) and an `int` (`-1`) it will convert the `bit` to an `int` so that the result is an `int` value.

The expression is not [SARGable](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/), but in this case the OP has stated that the operation is being performed on a single row already identified by PK so the performance of the comparison is not significant.

Note that this is a case of introducing a value (`-1`) that *cannot* occur in the original data's data type (`bit`). It is not the same as picking an arbitrary *magic value* that probably won't occur, e.g. the year `1800` is much too far in the past to ever turn up in a `DateSold` column. Except for real estate and various other things.

Bonus tip:

A handy way to confirm the behavior is by using [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to display the data type of the result:

```
declare @B as Bit = 1;
select SQL_Variant_Property( Coalesce( @B, -1 ), 'BaseType' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I appreciate the bonus tip as well.